# cURL library is not loaded google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl

I'm trying to build a simple PHP web page on google app engine.
I'm getting the following error on loading page!

**cURL library is not loaded**

I've also read on google app engine documentation page that cURL extension is pre-installed and enabled on system...! 
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime)

here is my code

```
    <?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    $api = new \Kavenegar\KavenegarApi("6C5846314B3***********62644E6A49663031307967442F565256634958373754593D");
    $sender = "10004346";
    $message = "Test message!";
    $receptor = array("0901***6780");
    $result = $api->Send($sender, $receptor, $message);
    if ($result) {
        foreach ($result as $r) {
            echo "messageid = $r->messageid";
            echo "message = $r->message";
            echo "status = $r->status";
            echo "statustext = $r->statustext";
            echo "sender = $r->sender";
            echo "receptor = $r->receptor";
            echo "date = $r->date";
            echo "cost = $r->cost";
        }
    }
}
catch(\Kavenegar\Exceptions\ApiException $e) {

    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
catch(\Kavenegar\Exceptions\HttpException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you are even using `cURL` in your code.  Form the link you provided, this is how you'd use it.  First, initialize it:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Metadata-Flavor: Google'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
return curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I don't use curl. the API that I'm using is using it

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, the php-curl library is not installed on the machine you're using for deploying and running your app.

Here is how you can install it (this is for Debian/Ubuntu, for other OS check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php))

First, you should make sure you have the latest version of your software, you can do that by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The installation depends on the version of PHP installed on your local machine. To check which version you have, use this command:

```
php -version
```

After confirming the version, you can use one of the following commands to add the php-curl library:

- For PHP 7.0: `sudo apt-get install php-curl`
- For PHP 5.6: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl`
- For PHP 5.5: `sudo apt-get install php5.5-curl`

This way your API can detect the library and use it on your code.